# JOOQ + Gradle: How to define multiple schemas for JOOQ generator?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, jooq

I want to setup JOOQ generator. The problem is to set multiple schemas in `build.gradle`. I know how to do it with maven:

```
<schemata>
  <schema>
    <inputSchema>schema1</inputSchema>
  </schema>
  <schema>
    <inputSchema>schema2</inputSchema>
  </schema>
</schemata>
```

I know how to do it with build.gradle.kts:

```
schemata.addAll(
    arrayOf(
        SchemaMappingType()
            .withInputSchema("data"),
         SchemaMappingType()
            .withInputSchema("dictionaries")
    )
)
```

But I don't know syntax how to do it in `gradle.build` on Groovy.

Please, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [`gradle-jooq-plugin`](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin), so

- here's an example on how to use the groovy DSL:
  https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/tree/master/example/use_groovy_dsl
- another one here:
  https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin#gradle-groovy-dsl-4

Just write:

```
schemata {
  schema {
    inputSchema = 'data'
  }
  schema {
    inputSchema = 'dictionaries'
  }
}
```